# don't allow split words

Tags: html, css

I have html

```
<div class="col-md-4">...</div>
<div class="col-md-4">...</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

And if I use mobile device I get

```
Lorem Ip-
sum
```

But I want to get

```
Lorem 
Ipsum
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `col-xs-6` for mobile devices.

Comment: Can you please give a reproducible example? [In my testing](https://jsfiddle.net/pw43hkv6/), it's impossible to make it wrap that way with default CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unnecessary to edit the bootstrap columns to ensure that the text fits the column. If you need simple spacing to mimic the enter key, just add the `<br>` element directly after Lorem

```
<div class="col-md-4">...</div>
<div class="col-md-4">...</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Lorem <br> Ipsum</div>
```

**EDIT**: upon looking at your question, you could have been referring to the fact that you wanted to only space out mobile, but not on a desktop size. In order to do this, you would have to add a br class, but make it only visible to xs (extra small) and sm (small) classes. You could add more if you want, but those two should cover most of mobile.

```
<div class="col-md-4">...</div>
<div class="col-md-4">...</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Lorem <br class = "visible-xs visible-sm"> Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: The `<wbr>` tag is another option, but it's not supported in IE :(